# Помогите правильно построить график Google Chart + nodejs

Tags: node.js, диаграммы, график

Здравствуйте, необходимо передать массив с сервера(nodejs) на клиент, чтобы потом по нему строить график. Я передаю массив, но на клиенте пишет, что это не массив. Где ошибка в коде?

Сервер:

```
app.post('/averageTimeInQueue', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = [
        [2012, 1000, 400, 232],
        [2005, 1170, 460, 421],
        [2006, 660, 1120, 4324]
    ];
    res.send(data);
});
```

Клиент:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
      data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

      data.addRows(averageTimeInQueue);
      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        width: 600,
        height: 350,
        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
}

function averageTimeInQueue(){
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/averageTimeInQueue",
        async: false,
        type: 'POST'
    }).responseText;
    return jsonData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно не массив, вы же его как текст отправляете. Сериализируйте его в json

на сервере `res.send(JSON.stringify(data));`

на клиенте `data.addRows(averageTimeInQueue())` вместо `data.addRows(averageTimeInQueue)` и

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "/averageTimeInQueue",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    type: 'POST'
}).responseText;
return JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Comment: так все равно пишет что не массив

Comment: @Andrei на клиента в строке data.addRows(averageTimeInQueue) поставьте скобки data.addRows(averageTimeInQueue())

Comment: тоже пишет что не массив, как-то надо преобразовать в массив наверное

Comment: @Andrei это очень странно, при dataType: "json" он должен парситься. Но исправьте return jsonData на return JSON.parse(jsonData), так будет работать

Comment: спасибо, так работает)